# Need help in converting the code from couchdb to couchbase

Tags: c#, couchdb, couchbase

I have same view in couchbase and couchdb. The name of the view is "TotalPosts"
I am pasting my view code below:

This is map:

```
 function(doc) {
    emit("Total", 1);
        emit("TotalParticipants", doc.participants.length);
        if(doc.status == "1"){
            emit("Open", 1);
        } else if(doc.status == "2") {
            emit("Wah", parseInt(doc.wah_points));
        }
    }
```

This is the reduce code:

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
}
```

The result of the view will be like this:

```
Key                    value

Open                     7
Total                    8
TotalParticipants        20
Wah                      50
```

Now i am able to execute and retrieve the view result in couchdb using this code:

```
public IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> GetAllStatistics()
         {
             oCouchDB.SetDefaultDesignDoc("Statistics");

             ViewOptions voStats = new ViewOptions();
             voStats.GroupLevel = 1;
             voStats.Stale = true;

             var results = oCouchDB.View("TotalPosts", voStats);

             return results.Rows;

        }
```

Now this is my code for couchbase:

```
public IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> GetAllStatistics()
         {
             var results = oCouchbase.GetView("Statistics", "TotalPosts");
             return-----// what is the equivalent code here

        }
```

Kindly help me out....

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase returns a JSON object just like CouchDB does. Should work with the same code, or inspect the 'results' variable to see what's inside.